# What features of Rational Application Developer for WebSphere make you the most productive

Tags: websphere, rad

I am mainly interested in the 'integration features' between the IDE and the application server.

One example would be GUI editors for various server specific deployment descriptors.

Another  example, from the NetBeans IDE integration with GlassFish, is the ability to:

- edit a java file that is part of a
  web application,
- save the file and
- see the effect of the change that you
  just saved in the browser (without a
  bunch of reloading).

Please include a link to any reference to the feature in user docs, if you have it at the tips of your fingers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over my years using RAD, the feature I'd recommend everybody to use would be its uninstaller...

Seriously though, RAD's advantage used to be IBM's plugins for Web / J2EE development; over the years, though, the Eclipse community has been making great progress with WTP and JST, so for most J2EE development you should do fine using Eclipse+WTP+JST... which are free (comparing RAD with 5-10K USD licensing fees. Per machine, that is).

Answer (score 0):

One person suggested that the 'Web site navigation' tooling was useful.